# R: How to check if a matrix is different of a matrix with zero's

Tags: r, matrix, zero

I've got different matrices and of different sizes (the program creates my matrices so I don't know how they look like). Now I want to check if a matrix is different of the zero matrix. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in this way:

```
all(mat == 0)
```

The function `all` checks if the condition `mat == 0` is verified for all elements of your matrix `mat`.

Comment: This will be subject to floating point errors. See for example when testing with this example borrowed from R Inferno: `mat <- .3 / 3 - .1`. Instead, do `all(abs(mat) < .Machine$double.eps)`